# The number of solutions of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials

Consider real polynomial equations
$$
P_1(x,y)=0, ~~~P_2(x,y)=0  \tag{1}
$$
For example,
$$
x+y=6, ~~~x-y=2
$$
has one solution $x=4,y=2$.  But
$$
a+b =x+y,~~~a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2
$$
has two solutions $x=a,y=b$ or $x=b,y=a$.   Then, how to know how many solution (1) has ?

I know nothing about this subject. If it's too difficult,  just considering about quadratic polynomial equations is enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some cases for of system quadratic equation I hope you understand.

**Case1:**
when one equation is linear and other equation is quadratic then this system have solution of two ordered pair
For example $x+y=7$ and $x^2-xy+y^2=13$ have solution (4,3),(3,4).

**Case2:**
when both equation are quadratic but missing the xy therms then this system also have solution two ordered pairs
For example $x^2+y^2+4x=1$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2$ have solution (-3,2),(-1,-2).

**Case3:**
When both equation are quadratic but only contain $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms then this system have solution of two ordered pairs for example $x^2+y^2=25$ and $2x^2+3y^2=6$ have solution (3,4).

**Case4:**
When one equation are full quadratic homogeneous in xy then system have solution of 4 ordered pairs for example $x^2-3xy+2y^2=0$ and $2x^2-3x+y^2=24$ have solution ($\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{2}$,$\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{2}$) , ($\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{2}$,$\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{2}$) , $(\frac{-8}{3}$,$\frac{-4}{3})$ , (4,2).

On the other hand if we are in system of linear equations then there are many other rules of matrices like Cramer's Rule, inversion rule, echelon forms and linear equation  may have finite or infinite solutions may be consistent or inconsistent depends upon equation.